# React JS Child objects not showing as valid

Tags: reactjs, redux

I know this is a repeat question but I'm sorry, I can't find an answer. I'm trying to import data into a React/Redux `Quiz` Component, but i'm getting the error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
>   with keys {answer, text}). If you meant to render a collection of
>   children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
>   of `Quiz`.

Here's my data file:

```
export const exampleQuestions = [
  {
    Question: 1,
    type: 'example',
    set: 1,
    text: 'Which one is true?',
    answers:
    [
      {
        answer: 'A',
        text: 'sometext',
      },
      {
        answer: 'B',
        text: 'sometext',
      },
      {
        answer: 'C',
        text: 'Neither of the above'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Question: 2,
    type: 'example',
    set: 1,
    text: 'Which one is true?',
    answers:
    [
      {
        answer: 'A',
        text: 'Sometext',
      },
      {
        answer: 'B',
        text: 'sometext',
      },
      {
        answer: 'C',
        text: 'Neither of the above'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Question: 3,
    type: 'example',
    set: 1,
    text: 'Which one is true?',
    answers:
    [
      {
        Answer: 'A',
        text: 'Sometext',
      },
      {
        Answer: 'B',
        text: 'sometext',
      },
      {
        Answer: 'C',
        text: 'Neither of the above'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Question: 4,
    type: 'example',
    set: 1,
    text: 'Which one is true?',
    answers:
    [
      {
        Answer: 'A',
        text: 'sometext',
      },
      {
        Answer: 'B',
        text: 'sometext'
      },
      {
        Answer: 'C',
        text: 'Neither of the above'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here's my `Quiz` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { chunk, now } from '../utils'

class Quiz extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      answers: new Array(this.props.question).fill('e'),
      chosenAnswers: []
    }
  }

  onAnswerSelected() {
    let answers = [this.state.answers]
    answers[qindex] = String.fromCharCode(97 + i)
    this.setState({ ...state,answers })

  }

  render() {
    const { set, enterAnswers, id, timed, questions } = this.props
    console.log(questions);
    const { qindex, text, answers } = questions

    return (
      <div>
          <div key={qindex}>
            <h4>{text}</h4>
            {answers.map((a, i) => (
              <label key={i} style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={`${qindex}_${i}`}
                  checked={
                    this.state.answers[qindex] === String.fromCharCode(97 + i)
                  }
                  onChange={this.onAnswerSelected.bind}
                  value={String.fromCharCode(97 + i)}
                />
                &nbsp;{a}
              </label>
            ))}
          </div>
        <div
          className="button"
          onClick={() => enterAnswers(id, this.state.selected, now())}
          style={{
            border: '1px solid black',
            backgroundColor: 'purple',
            display: 'inline-block',
            color: 'white',
            padding: 10
          }}
        >
          Save answers
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Quiz.propTypes = {
  set: PropTypes.array,
  enterAnswers: PropTypes.func,
  id: PropTypes.number,
  timed: PropTypes.number
}

export default Quiz
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the questions property that is passed as props in Quiz component? Is this the exampleQuestions array? Or is it just one question object?

Comment: please post which line you are getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to render an object `a` at this part of the code:

```
answers.map((a, i) => (
              <label key={i} style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={`${qindex}_${i}`}
                  checked={
                    this.state.answers[qindex] === String.fromCharCode(97 + i)
                  }
                  onChange={this.onAnswerSelected.bind}
                  value={String.fromCharCode(97 + i)}
                />
                &nbsp;{a}   <----- the erroneous part
              </label>
        ))
```

As error note says, objects cannot be rendered as such. This object contains `answer` and `text` fields. You should render each of those properties separately instead of rendering the object itself. For example you can do:

```
answers.map((a, i) => (
              <label key={i} style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={`${qindex}_${i}`}
                  checked={
                    this.state.answers[qindex] === String.fromCharCode(97 + i)
                  }
                  onChange={this.onAnswerSelected.bind}
                  value={String.fromCharCode(97 + i)}
                />
                <div>{a.answer}, {a.text}</div>
              </label>
        ))
```

Comment: This one helped the most - thankyou, but the questions now loop through only the even numbers....

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the answers.map to a variable outside return.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I hope this will work.

```
render() {
    const { set, enterAnswers, id, timed, questions } = this.props
    console.log(questions);
    const { qindex, text, answers } = questions

    return ( 
        <div>
           { this.questions() }
        </div>
        );
}

questions() {
 return questions.map((question) =>{
    return (
       <div key={question.Question}>
            <h4>{question.text}</h4>
            { this.answer(question.answers) }
        </div>
        <div
            className="button"
            onClick={() => enterAnswers(id, this.state.selected, now())}
            style={{
                border: '1px solid black',
                backgroundColor: 'purple',
                display: 'inline-block',
                color: 'white',
                 padding: 10
            }}
            >
             Save answers
        </div>
    );
 });
}

answer(answer) {
   return answer.map((a, i) =>{
     return (
        <label key={i} style={{ display: 'block' }}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          id={`${qindex}_${i}`}
          checked={
            this.state.answers[qindex] === String.fromCharCode(97 + i)
          }
          onChange={this.onAnswerSelected.bind}
          value={String.fromCharCode(97 + i)}
        />
        &nbsp;{a.text}
       </label>
     );
   });


}
```